# "System doesn't have USB option" when attempting to boot to lubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-10, acer, rufus

I'm attempting to dual-boot lubuntu from USB on my Windows 10 Acer Aspire 5. To try to boot, I held the shift key while pressing restart. It took me to the advanced startup options, and I selected "Use a Device". I clicked the USB but it said "System Doesn't Have USB option. Please select other boot option in boot manager menu." I pressed "ok" and it gave me a menu with only 1 option. So I pressed "enter" and it just booted windows. I tried changing the UEFI firmware settings to change it to "Legacy Mode" But when I pressed the arrow keys or enter nothing happened, though I could move around in other menus. I am not sure what's happening here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be a hardware problem to me (specific to your device), however you've provided no details on what Lubuntu you're talking about, and currently there are three supported installer choices available, and we don't know which you've tried (did you try an appropriate one for uEFI, one installer option (two ISOs) is not intended for uEFI devices). Did you verify your ISO was downloaded perfectly? (as per instructions/manual), and the write to your installation media was likewise flawless (how this is done varies on release, but we don't have details..)

Comment: might BIOS secure boot option have any bearing on it?